# How to pipe an output tibble into further calculations without saving the tibble as a separate object in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am having a hard time manipulating a tibble output that I receive after piping (using dplyr pipe %>%) a data frame through a series of steps. This code below returns a 2 x 3 tibble ouput:

`sr_df %>% group_by(ResolutionViolated) %>% tally() %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% mutate(total = sum(n))`

This gives me a count of service requests that are and aren't violated (or simply put, late). This is well and good, but I want to be able to manipulate this same tibble further without having to save the tibble as an object.

Why? Because this way, I can filter my data frame (sr_df) before this piping operations, by company/account, priority, and other factors. I am able to filter with an if function, but this filter will not have an impact on the newly created tibble object. So I am looking to do something like this:

`sr_df %>% group_by(ResolutionViolated) %>% tally() %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% mutate(total = sum(n)) %>% round(tibble[1,2]/tibble$total*100, digits = 2)`

I am an R and Coding Noob. Don't hold back - I just want to learn; learn quick and learn right. Any answers are appreciated. Thank you!

I have looked at this: [R: Further subset a selection using the pipe %>% and placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474882/r-further-subset-a-selection-using-the-pipe-and-placeholder)
but I don't think I get it.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and the desired output. Ideally, one would easily copy/paste your code in her or his own R console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your caase, you can further manipulate the tibble you have generated using `dplyr` functions.

Note the existence of `mutate_at` and `summarize_at`, that lets you transform a set of columns with the option to select them by column position.

This, using `.` as a placeholder for the tibble you are currently manipulating, and calling an anonymous function inside `mutate_at`, will give you the result you expect.

```
sr_df %>%
  group_by(ResolutionViolated) %>%
  tally() %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(n)) %>% 
  mutate_at(.cols = c(1, 2), 
            .funs = function(column) round(column / .$total * 100, digits = 2))
```

Comment: Thank you Juan! This was exactly what I was looking for.