# dplyr: group_by & mutate variable can't call mean/sd functions

Tags: r, dplyr

Sorry if the title is a bit convoluted, as I didn't know how else to explain this issue. Basically, I'm attempting to mutate a **percent of group** variable utilizing `dplyr`. However, I'm running into an issue where the new calculated variable appears numeric, and even calculates when using `summary()`, but will not allow me to call `mean()` or `sd()` without throwing me the following error:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(., group_pct) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Here are some examples of what is going on.

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(group_pct = hp / sum(hp)) %>% 
  summary()
```

[image]

Note: group_pct is calculating correctly when called via `summary()`...

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(group_pct = hp / sum(hp)) %>% 
  mean(group_pct)
```

[image]

...but when I call for the mean here, it cannot complete the function. Even when I use `ungroup()` and/or `na.rm = TRUE`, the function still doesn't work. I don't understand what the issue is here.

---

EDIT: For clarification, I'm hoping to do something like this...

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(group_pct = hp / sum(hp)) %>% 
  paste0('Words: ', mean(group_pct))
```

Hoping for this final result:

```
Words: 0.09375
```

...which I don't think I can use `summarize()` for, hence my non-inclusion of it from the start. Apologies for any inconveniences.

Comment: From my personal experience, expected output is most helpful. Do you just want a character vector that is the length of the number of rows of `mtcars` with each element of the form `"Words: #.###"`?

Comment: My bad, edited again for expected output. I'm hoping for one phrase and one numerical result which is the average of the rowwise group proportions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the baseR function `with()`.

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(group_pct = hp / sum(hp)) %>%
  with(paste0('Words: ', mean(group_pct)))

[1] "Words: 0.09375"
```

The issue with your original attempt is that `group_pct` is not defined in the global environment, so you get the error message, when it can't locate it in the lookup.

`with` is the syntactic sugar that tells R to evaluate the `paste0()` function call within the environment of the data frame being passed by pipe. So it finds `group_pct` and returns your expected result.

Comment: You really understood OP!

Comment: It's a warning message, not an error, since they are passing group_pct as the second arg to mean, like `mean(mtcars, absolutely + any + gibberish)` or `mean(mtcars)`. Also, maybe of interest: with magrittr you can use a different pipe operator instead of with: `mtcars %$% mean(disp)`

Answer (score 4):

#### Per OP's Clarification:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(group_pct = hp / sum(hp)) %>%
  pull(group_pct) %>%
  mean() %>%
  paste0("Words: ", .)

[1] "Words: 0.09375"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how you're piping into the `mean` function. Look at your error message:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(., group_pct)
```

You're trying to get the mean of the `group_pct` column of the piped data frame, but instead what's happening is `mean` is receiving both the entire piped data frame (the `.` represents the output of the pipe) and an object `group_pct` which does may or may not exist.

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38475455/8366499

If you want to subset the piped data.frame in the mean function, you need to use curly braces `{}` so the call to mean gets treated like an expression, not a function call. Then, you can subset the `.` object as desired:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    mutate(group_pct = hp / sum(hp)) %>% 
    {mean(.$group_pct)} %>%
    paste0('Words: ', .)

[1] "Words: 0.09375"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(group_pct = hp / sum(hp)) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  select(group_pct) %>%
  map(function(x) paste0(" Word ", x))
```

and the result is:

```
"Word 0.03125"
```

Comment: @medavis6 maybe it is a little lat, but now my answer works as well :(