# use assign / create new object with value (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to create a new variable with the value of column number in my `DF` by its name.
I have managed to do this:

```
firstCol <- which(colnames(Mydf) == "Cars")
```

It takes the column number of the column with the name "Cars" and set its number to the object firstCol. It works well and good on base.

latly, I've been using `dplyr` and pipes and I'm trying to create a variable and do the same thing by using pipes but I'm unable to do this - use this line but in pipes %>%
Can you help me?
thanks,
Ido

Comment: Hi, Can you ```dput()``` some data will be helpfult to help. ```firstCol  <-  subset(DF,DF$Mydf == 'Cars')```   is that something you want?

Comment: hey! thank you but I dont really understanrd,
this line works perfect:
firstCol <- which(colnames(Mydf) == "Cars")
but how do I use it in pipes?
>%> firstCol <- which(colnames(Mydf) == "Cars")
>%>

is not working

Comment: you can try  ```firstCol <- Mydf %>% select(Cars)```

Comment: this one create a df with a column.
the thing I want is to get the index of the column into a new variable at the global env. (the result is a new variable called firstcol and has the value 17 for example)

Comment: Refre this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474882/r-further-subset-a-selection-using-the-pipe-and-placeholder.  hope this will help as answer could be duplicate if it is already available.

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` way to do this is `select`.

Here is an example using some made up data:

```
df <- data.frame(cars = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE),
                 mpg = runif(100, 15, 45),
                 color = sample(c("green", "red","blue", "silver"), 
                                100, replace = TRUE)) %>% tibbble()  
df %>% select(cars)
# A tibble: 100 x 1
   cars 
   <chr>
 1 R    
 2 V    
 3 I    
 4 Q    
 5 P    
 6 D    
 7 J    
 8 Q    
 9 R    
10 A    
# ... with 90 more rows
```

You can also remove columns with `select(-col_name)`

```
df %>% select(-mpg)
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   cars  color 
   <chr> <chr> 
 1 R     blue  
 2 V     silver
 3 I     red   
 4 Q     green 
 5 P     silver
 6 D     silver
 7 J     green 
 8 Q     blue  
 9 R     red   
10 A     silver
# ... with 90 more rows
```